# Aside from git hook is there an internal GIT command to watch files for commits

Tags: git, githooks, git-pull

As for as my knowledge with git hooks, almost everything can be done from hooking every commit to a build checker, code ruling (i.e., checkstyle, etc.). and many more. However, things can be a little bit different especially if you don't have any authority on the repository host.

I'm looking for solutions for watch certain files on my remote and/or local repository (i.e., files that I've modified and keep track of the changes from my last previous push). Maybe like this scenario, given a list of files, when I invoke *git pull* it will check files that have been updated and show me the log of each files (more like *git diff*).

Is there a way to make this possible? Let me know if you have other options or concerns regarding the content.

Answer (score 0):

There's a variety of client-side hooks that can be invoked without having authority over the repository host. For instance, I use the post-merge hook in a project to locally run a script if specific files have been changed. Despite its misleading name, the post-merge hook is invoked after every pull: "This hook is invoked by git merge, which happens when a git pull is done on a local repository" (from https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks )